# Very new to express and mongodb with gridfs-stream

Tags: image, mongodb, express, upload, gridfs-stream

and thanks in advance for any help you guys can give me.  I am trying to use mongodb, mongoose, gridfs-strea, and express to store img files on mongodb.
I do not want to store the file in a folder. I want gfs.createWriteStream to take the file directly from app.post from express. App.post is currently saving some strings through a schema model into mongodb.
The form that routes to app.post contains strings and a input for img file.

I tried to do this(dnimgfront being the name of the input):

```
dnimgfront:req.pipe(gfs.createWriteStream('req.body.dnimgfront'))
```

I am getting back.

```
TypeError: Object function Grid(db, mongo) {
 if (!(this instanceof Grid)) {
   return new Grid(db, mongo);
 }

 mongo || (mongo = Grid.mongo ? Grid.mongo : undefined);
```

My problem is I have to be able to store the img and the strings from the same app.post save function.  Any ideas?

What I'm using to connect to mongodb is:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/veeltaxi');

var con=mongoose.connection;

con.once('open', function(){
    console.log('connected to mongodb succesfully!')
});
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need an instead of gridfs-stream:

```
var GridStream = require('gridfs-stream');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var gfs = new GridStream(mongoose.connection,mongodb);
```

At which point you can create the write stream and pipe:

```
var writeStream = gfs.createWriteStream({
   filename: filename, // the name of the file
   content_type: mimetype, // somehow get mimetype from request,
   mode: 'w' // ovewrite
});

req.pipe(writeStream);
```

However, at this time the Node.js MongoDB Driver is at version 2.0 which uses Streams 2, so there is no reason to use `gridfs-stream` if you're using that version of the `mongodb` lib. [See the source code for v2.0.13.](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/V2.0.13/lib/gridfs/grid_store.js#L1317-L1429) FYI, the stream that is implemented in the updated driver is Duplex. (Aside: gridfs-stream has its share of problems, and while actively maintained, is not very frequent.)

Comment: can I call re.pipe(writeStream(req.body.dnimgfront)), meaning I pass the req.body that stores the img from the form to the writeStream? This would be within the app.post function.

Comment: @jsrosas you can call it inline like that, yes, but not the way you have it. are you using multipart? what express middleware are you using? etc?

Comment: body-parser with the method-override urlenconded enconded extended = true

Comment: I am developing in c9.io so far i've not had to require mongodb. it already comes installed do i still have to require? Thanks for your help so far zammnuts

Comment: @jsrosas `body-parser` doesn't handle streaming nor multi-part content IIRC, i would use something like [`multiparty`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiparty). I've never used c9.io, but gridfs-stream needs an instance of mongodb to initialize correctly, so make sure you get it somehow and pass it in.

Comment: I did a npm link to the global of npm so far that works.  Multiparty I will have to research.  Can multiparty replace completely body-parser? will i will need the method-override?